# How to get localized timer label like UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdatepicker

I want to get localized timer labels on my developing application.
For example, "hour,hours" and "min" on en_US, "時間" and "分" on ja_JP, "ora,ore" and "min" on it_IT etc.
UIDatePickerCountDownTimer mode can display them, but there seems no method to access.

I studied NSDateFormatter,NSLocale,UIDatePicker,etc, but I couldn't find the solution.
Please help me...

Comment: Can you show a more explicit example of the output you would like to show? Would it be something like `9 hours, 20 minutes and 34 seconds`?

Comment: Thanks, my app saves amount of seconds, for example 5400. Then I want to display it to "1hour 30min" on en_US locale and "1分 30秒" on ja_JP.

Comment: @colori  Did you ever find a solution to this? My initial thought is to subclass UIDatePicker and add custom labels over the default hour/minute labels.

Answer (score 0):

The text of the "hour" and "min" labels on `UIDatePicker` is not accessible to developers.  If you want to use that text in your own app in a different context, you'll have to provide it yourself.

Of course, if you feel like this is something the frameworks should provide, please [file a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com) requesting this enhancement.

Comment: Thank you. I think so... UIDatePicker may get labels information on background proccess. I don't have to access it via UIDatePicker, but I want to know the origin.

Comment: @colori based on your comment to the question, you'll have to supply the "hours" and "分" stuff yourself.

Comment: Ok. It will hard for me to prepare many languages combination, so I'll use simplified "hour(s)" and "min" label. Thank you.